# Oracle: Trigger to replace row from related table B to spatial table A for records with equal IDs

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, arcgis

Database / Trigger Diagram

[image: Database / Trigger Diagram]

I am working within an Oracle spatial database and I was wondering if someone could show me a SQL trigger to replace an entire row in table A every time a matching record is updated in table B. So in other words when a record in table B is updated the same record via matching F_ID in table A is replaced with the new data from table B.

The reason for this odd system is due to permission levels via the ArcGIS collector application. We want the field crew to be able to edit all columns through the application—but not be able to create or move any assets. The other major reason is to preserve the integrity of our data model and put all other information in the related table. This particular set up would allow the crews to edit data in the related table without having edit rights to the main table (so they cannot move the location of assets) and then the trigger would update table A with the new data.

Table B is a related table and in reality has more columns than table A and table A is the spatial table with columns only related to the data model.

Forgive my bad trigger I am still learning to work with them and have a limit
understanding how to work with them. I know I have this all wrong and probably need an if statement about if table B F_ID == table A F_ID then replace etc.

Also table B is a many to one relationship with table A. The idea behind this is that table B will keep a record of all the previous assets because we have an asset management software with associated work orders based off another unique T_ID field. The F_ID represents the asset location ID and T_ID is the unique ID for the asset so the asset management software will be able to preserve a link to the old asset for records and analysis.

I would appreciate useful feedback/help and would like to avoid being told what I am attempting is terrible or breaking the norms of database management etc. Please help me and if not at least be nice and constructive. I really appreciate any help that could be offered.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "REPLACE_RDATA" AFTER INSERT ON TABLE B 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE A (F_ID,DBH,SPECIES,HEIGHT,FAMILY,NOTES)
  VALUES (:new.DBH,:new.SPECIES,:new.HEIGHT,:new.FAMILY,:new.NOTES);
END;
```

For example:

### Table A

```
F_ID,   DBH,   Species,   Height,   Family,   Notes,   T_ID
1,   10.5,   Acer rubrum,   25,   Sapindaceae,   Gifted by person xyz,   1
2,   28.2,   Carya illinoinensis,   39,   Juglandaceae,   Next to building 2,   2
3,   26,   Pinus virginiana,   52.5,   Pinaceae,   Planted by xyz for opening celebration,   3
```

### Table B

```
F_ID,   DBH,   Species,   Height,   Family,   Notes,   T_ID
1,   10.5,   Acer negundo,   25,   Sapindaceae,   Gifted by person xyz: misidentified,   1
2,   31,   Carya illinoinensis,   42,   Juglandaceae,   Next to building 2,   2
3,   26,   Pinus virginiana,   52.5,   Pinaceae,   Planted by xyz for opening celebration,   3
2,   3,   Carya ovata,   15,   Juglandaceae,   Replaced the pecan tree,   4
```

### Updated Table A

```
F_ID,   DBH,   Species,   Height,   Family,   Notes,   T_ID
1,   10.5,   Acer negundo,   25,   Sapindaceae,   Gifted by person xyz: misidentified,   1
2,   3,   Carya ovata,   15,   Juglandaceae,   replaced the pecan tree,   2
3,   26,   Pinus virginiana,   52.5,   Pinaceae,   Planted by xyz for opening celebration,   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a row in table A for every row in table B.

Change the trigger so it also fires on update.
Insert into table_A when inserting, Update table_a when updating.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "REPLACE_RDATA" AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLE B 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
     INSERT INTO TABLE A (F_ID,DBH,SPECIES,HEIGHT,FAMILY,NOTES)
     VALUES (:new.DBH,:new.SPECIES,:new.HEIGHT,:new.FAMILY,:new.NOTES);
  ELSE
     UPDATE TABLE_A 
     set DBH = :new.DBH
     ... -- rest of the columns
     where F_ID = :new.F_ID;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I will edit my post with this however, I meant to say that this is a little more complicated because table B is a many to one relationship with table A. The idea behind this is that table B will keep a record of all the previous assets because we have an asset management software with associated work orders based off another unique T_ID field! The F_ID represents an asset location ID and T_ID is the unique ID for the asset so the asset management software will be able to preserve a link to the old asset. I am sorry about that confusion. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried using this trigger to see if I could at least get this to work even though it is 1:1. The trigger complies successfully but when I edit the data I am getting a ORA-06512 on line 3
and a ORA-04088 error during execution of trigger.

Comment: I kept getting Oracle errors with your code but I modified it to the following and it worked without error. 


`create or replace trigger REPLACE_RDATA AFTER Insert ON table B FOR EACH ROW BEGIN Update table A Set F_ID = :new.F_ID, DBH = :new.DBH, SPECIES = :new.SPECIES, HEIGHT = :new.HEIGHT, FAMILY = :new.FAMILY, NOTES = :new.NOTES Where T_ID = :new.T_ID; END;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a procedure (instead of the trigger), which does the insert into table_b and updates table_a, whenever a row is added to table_b. Example (tested with Oracle 12c and 11g, respectively):

Table_A - "master", contains a list of all recorded plants, including the latest observation:

```
create table table_a (
  f_id number unique     
, dbh  number       
, species varchar2(64) 
, height number(6,2)     
, family varchar2(64) 
, notes varchar2(4000) 
, t_id number
) ;

insert into table_a ( f_id, dbh, species, height, family, notes, t_id )
select 1                 as F_ID
, 10.5                   as DBH
, 'Acer rubrum'          as Species
, 25                     as Height
, 'Sapindaceae'          as Family
, 'Gifted by person xyz' as Notes
, 1000                   as T_ID from dual union all
select 2, 28.2, 'Carya illinoinensis', 39, 'Juglandaceae', 'Next to building 2', 2000 from dual union all
select 3, 26, 'Pinus virginiana', 52.5, 'Pinaceae', 'Planted by xyz for opening celebration', 3000 from dual ;
```

Table_A contains ...

```
SQL> select * from table_a ;
F_ID  DBH   SPECIES              HEIGHT  FAMILY        NOTES                                   T_ID  
1     10.5  Acer rubrum          25      Sapindaceae   Gifted by person xyz                    1000  
2     28.2  Carya illinoinensis  39      Juglandaceae  Next to building 2                      2000  
3     26    Pinus virginiana     52.5    Pinaceae      Planted by xyz for opening celebration  3000
```

Table_B - for "observations" (empty)

```
create table table_b (
  f_id number references table_a( f_id )     
, dbh  number       
, species varchar2(64) 
, height number(6,2)     
, family varchar2(64) 
, notes varchar2(4000) 
, t_id number unique
) ;
```

Procedure that {1} allows us to add records to table_b, and {2} updates table_a in due course.

Package spec

```
create or replace package dendrology
is
  procedure add_record(
     f_id_     number
   , dbh_      number
   , species_  varchar2
   , height_   number
   , family_   varchar2
   , notes_    varchar2
   , t_id_     number
  );
end;
/
```

Package body

```
create or replace package body dendrology
is
  procedure add_record(
     f_id_     number
   , dbh_      number
   , species_  varchar2
   , height_   number
   , family_   varchar2
   , notes_    varchar2
   , t_id_     number
  ) is
  begin
    -- insert into table_b first
    insert into table_b ( f_id, dbh, species, height, family, notes, t_id )
      values (  f_id_, dbh_, species_, height_, family_, notes_, t_id_  );
    commit ;
    -- update table_A
    update table_a
    set dbh = dbh_
      , species = species_
      , height = height_
      , family = family_
      , notes = notes_
      , t_id = t_id_
    where f_id = f_id_ ;
    commit ;
  end add_record ;
end dendrology;
/
```

Test the procedure: add some "observations".

```
begin
  dendrology.add_record(  
    1, 10.5, 'Acer negundo', 25, 'Sapindaceae', 'Gifted by person xyz: misidentified', 1000 
  ) ;
  dendrology.add_record(  
    2, 31, 'Carya illinoinensis', 42, 'Juglandaceae', 'Next to building 2', 2000
  ) ;
  dendrology.add_record(  
    3, 26, 'Pinus virginiana', 52.5, 'Pinaceae', 'Planted by xyz for opening celebration', 3000
  ) ;
  dendrology.add_record( 
    2,  3, 'Carya ovata', 15, 'Juglandaceae', 'Replaced the pecan tree',   4000
  );
end;
/
```

Check: TABLE_B

```
SQL> select * from table_b order by t_id ;
F_ID  DBH   SPECIES              HEIGHT  FAMILY        NOTES                                   T_ID  
1     10.5  Acer negundo         25      Sapindaceae   Gifted by person xyz: misidentified     1000  
2     31    Carya illinoinensis  42      Juglandaceae  Next to building 2                      2000  
3     26    Pinus virginiana     52.5    Pinaceae      Planted by xyz for opening celebration  3000  
2     3     Carya ovata          15      Juglandaceae  Replaced the pecan tree                 4000
```

Check: TABLE_A

```
SQL> select * from table_a ;
F_ID  DBH   SPECIES           HEIGHT  FAMILY        NOTES                                   T_ID  
1     10.5  Acer negundo      25      Sapindaceae   Gifted by person xyz: misidentified     1000  
2     3     Carya ovata       15      Juglandaceae  Replaced the pecan tree                 4000  
3     26    Pinus virginiana  52.5    Pinaceae      Planted by xyz for opening celebration  3000
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cbdcfb1dae18d1e1a9ad6bd27ce4a57a).  NOTE: we assume that TABLE_A is already populated when the procedure is called.

Comment: Thank you for your help but after looking into using a procedure I need table A to be updated automatically as soon as new data is entered through the ArcGIS collector form. From my understanding this procedure would need to be executed as data is being entered into a console?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  Seems that the trigger is the right method for you.
Regarding the procedure and the console: I'd probably use APEX instead.